# What software can I use to download torrents

Tags: 13.10, downloads, bittorrent

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10, Saucy Salamander. I would like to install a different Linux distribution, but all of my download crash. I want to use a torrent instead. What software can I install to download torrents in Ubuntu? I used Utorrent in Windows 8 but I don't think they have that for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the default torrent client that ships with Ubuntu which is *Transmission*. If you would like something that more familiar to utorrent you can use *qBitTorrent*.

To open Transmission you can simple search for it in the Dash. To get *qBitTorrent* you have to go to the *Software Center* and then search for it and install it:

[image: USC]

This is what it looks like:

[image: qBittorrent]

Answer (score 1):

Use Transmission a simple torrent downloader. It's installed by default.